# Completely disable Django's CSRF protection in SVN Trunk

Tags: django, csrf

I've spend a few hours in frustration, trying to disable the CSRF which Django now tries to force on me, to no avail. Had anyone else tried this with more success? I'm fine with anything that works, except for a source patch (but monkeypatches are okay).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django, but am familiar with CSRF - out of curiosity, why do you want to disable CSRF protection?  In general, preventing CSRF attacks is a *good* thing.

Comment: Because i design intranet sites and because they are often accessed by non-humans over which i have no control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. But if you must, [try this](http://johnmc.co/llum/disable-csrf-protection-for-django-1-2/#more-198).

Comment: link is dead; not sure what it says

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually tried to disable it (never had the need), but I imagine it's just a matter of removing the CSRF middleware(s) from the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting in your settings.py.

Comment: I believe it is now enabled by default on the contrib apps.

Comment: No, it just flat out ignores what's in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES of my settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the csrf middleware and restarting the server. A lot of the time changes like that wont be loaded until afterward.